# Store delayed shell output to variable?

Tags: shell-script

I have a script which stores output of a command inside a variable like this:

my_var=$(command)

However, some of the output is not being stored in the variable, I am assuming because it is delayed... I am sure its delayed because it outputs the line I want to the screen after it stored the output in the variable and I tried processing it...

[EDIT]IMPORTANT! It turns out the output was going to stderr[/EDIT]

How do I get it to wait for the exit code (when it is 100% done outputting) before storing the output into the variable?

I did not post an example because *I thought* the users would complain it is nefarious, however it is not, and I am running the script on my own servers. Example as requested:

```
# Grab the output, so we can check for error... If error then retry same password after wait time
outpt="$(hydra -l $hydra_user -P $tmp_passwds $hydra_all_params $hydra_host $hydra_module)"

# Grep for "ssh protocol error" line
banln=$(echo "$outpt" | grep 'ssh protocol error')

# Show ban status, update wait_time
if [ "$banln" != "" ];then
    echo "[STATUS] Oops, we got banned! (increasing wait_time + 1 second)"
wait_time=$wait_time+1

# Start retry procedure until not banned

fi
```

The problem in this example is that the line I am looking for ([ERROR] ssh protocol error) seems to come after the command's output is stored in the variable

Comment: Please provide an example of what is happening, sticking as close to the actual command being run as possible. The current format of this question presents a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Uhhm... I just read the xy problem, its nothing close to it... But I added an example for clarity, as you asked for one.

Comment: The problem was that you were making an assumption about what was happening, and asking a question based on the assumption without providing us enough information to verify your point of view. Moving on from that...what happens if you append a space prefixed `2>&1` to the end of your `hydra` command? Does the problem go away?

Comment: The assumption was not really an assumption, its just how I chose to word it... I know for a fact the part I want is being output after the capturing was done. I apologize for my wording habits... I will try that and let you know so you can post it as an answer and I can accept it :)

Comment: YESSSS!!! I guess it was outputting to stderr... Thanks lots! Post as an answer and I will accept it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless this process is backgrounding itself or forking, it would not be due to the delay. You can verify this with a quick test:

```
# FOO=$(sleep 10; echo whee;); echo $FOO
whee
```

This command does not complete until the `sleep` finishes executing, and the message that is sent to standard out afterwards is successfully stored to the variable. From this, we can surmise a few things:

- The variable is not stored until the command completes.
- STDOUT remains connected for the full duration of the command.

At this point, one of two things is happening here:

- The message isn't being written to STDOUT: it was probably being written to STDERR instead.
- The command is in fact completing. (backgrounded, forked a subprocess, etc.)

*Usually* the problem is the former.

Comment: Yes Andrew B just figured it out, he had a hunch that it was going to stderr and it was :) I was going to accept his answer, but he hasnt posted it as an answer yet O-o

Comment: @kthx (psst, it's me)

Comment: Hahahhaa oops... Im a stoner, but havent been stoned in weeks lol... sorry didnt notice :P